# git push heroku master not working

Tags: heroku, nitrousio, nitrous

```
I am trying to push my code to heroku and this appears as an error:
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * 1.10.0.pre
       Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * 1.10.0.pre
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
```

I have tried the "bundle install" command and "bundle update" but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

What about the part that says:

```
and add the updated Gemfile.lock to version control
```

Is the Gemfile.lock included in your Git?